# How to make edges decorated with big dot in Graphviz?

Tags: graphviz

I want to have a big dot (or something similar) in the center of some edges.
The following code is the best I was able to produce.

```
digraph BDD {
  ordering = out;
  splines = true;
  edge [arrowhead="none"];
  node [shape = none, label = "SUM"] 0;
  node [shape = circle, label = "x"] 1;
  node [shape = circle, label = "y"] 2;
  node [shape = circle, label = "w"] 3;
  node [shape = none, label = "1"] 4;
  node [shape = circle, label = "z"] 5;
  node [shape = none, label = "1"] 6;
  node [shape = circle, label = "y"] 7;
  node [shape = circle, label = "w"] 8;
  node [shape = none, label = "1"] 9;
  0 -> 1;
  1 -> 2;
  1 -> 7 [arrowhead="dot"]; 
  2 -> 3;
  2 -> 5 [arrowhead="dot"];
  3 -> 4 [arrowhead="dot"]; 
  3 -> 4;
  5 -> 6 [arrowhead="dot"]; 
  5 -> 6;
  7 -> 5;
  7 -> 8;
  8 -> 9;
  8 -> 5;
}
```

This will produce the following image, which is not quite right, because dots are on the end of edges.

[image]

Can anybody suggest me a solution to produce this:

[image]

EDIT 1: using extra nodes as points produces unacceptable output.

```
digraph BDD {
  ordering = out;
  splines = true;
  edge [arrowhead="none"];
  node [shape = none, label = "SUM"] 0;
  node [shape = circle, label = "x"] 1;
  node [shape = circle, label = "y"] 2;
  node [shape = circle, label = "w"] 3;
  node [shape = none, label = "1"] 4;
  node [shape = circle, label = "z"] 5;
  node [shape = none, label = "1"] 6;
  node [shape = circle, label = "y"] 7;
  node [shape = circle, label = "w"] 8;
  node [shape = none, label = "1"] 9;
  0 -> 1;
  1 -> 2;
  node [shape = point width=0.1] p1p7;
  1 -> p1p7 -> 7; 
  2 -> 3;
  node [shape = point width=0.1] p2p5;
  2 -> p2p5 -> 5;
  node [shape = point width=0.1] p3p4;
  3 -> p3p4 -> 4; 
  3 -> 4;
  node [shape = point width=0.1] p5p6;
  5 -> p5p6 -> 6; 
  5 -> 6;
  7 -> 5;
  7 -> 8;
  8 -> 9;
  8 -> 5;
}
```

[image]

EDIT 2: I can also accept a graph where dots are not exactly on the center. They only must not touch the node, i.e. probably it would be OK if I could set/make the distance between the arrowhead and the node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can make an extra node (and an extra edge) to achieve that.

```
digraph {
    node [shape = circle]
    A
    C
    node [shape = point width=0.2]
    B
    edge [arrowhead=none]
    A -> B -> C
}
```

produces

[image]

---

EDIT:

You could layout your graph to a *.dot file where all nodes and edges are placed. then you could use your favorite programming language to read and modify that file. There is also some built-in script language I haven't tried yet. Finally you use the nop2-engine to convert the modified DOT-file to the image format of your choice. You have to find out how to place points on the Bezier splines. According to the documentation

```
splineType
    spline ( ';' spline )*
    where spline    =   (endp)? (startp)? point (triple)+
    and triple  =   point point point
    and endp    =   "e,%f,%f"
    and startp  =   "s,%f,%f"
```

we always have 4+3n (0 <= n) points per edge. these are 4tuples of cubic splines where the endpoint of one spline is the startpoint of the next spline. as the start-/endpoints are touched directly they are candidates for placing the dot if there are at least two splines (7 points). in general every point[4+3n] is a candidate. if we have a single spline this approach fails. we have to place a point on the spline. valid 4-tuples start at 0+3n and end with 3+3n.

you can use any valid 4-tuple of x/y coordinates to calculate a point on the spline

```
x = (x1 + 3*x2 + 3*x3 + x4)/8
```

this is a simple formular for divider 2. similar you can do for the y-coordinate.

Example:

```
digraph { rankdir = LR ranksep=1 nodesep=1 pad=0.5
    node [shape = circle]
    edge [arrowhead=none]
    { rank=same
        A -> B
        B -> C
        A -> C
    }
}
```

gives

```
digraph {
    graph [bb="0,0,74.575,252",
        nodesep=1,
        pad=0.5,
        rankdir=LR,
        ranksep=1
    ];
    node [label="\N",
        shape=circle
    ];
    edge [arrowhead=none];
    {
        graph [rank=same];
        A        [height=0.5,
            pos="56.575,234",
            width=0.5];
        B        [height=0.5,
            pos="56.575,126",
            width=0.5];
        A -> B       [pos="56.575,215.75 56.575,191.88 56.575,168.01 56.575,144.14"];
        C        [height=0.5,
            pos="56.575,18",
            width=0.5];
        A -> C       [pos="44.02,220.46 24.619,197.84 -9.2417,150.66 2.5745,108 10.795,78.323 31.695,48.606 44.952,31.836"];
        B -> C       [pos="56.575,107.75 56.575,83.878 56.575,60.01 56.575,36.141"];
    }
}
```

the edge from the line

```
        A -> C       [pos="44.02,220.46 24.619,197.84 -9.2417,150.66 2.5745,108 10.795,78.323 31.695,48.606 44.952,31.836"];
```

consists of 2 splines. we have one overlapping start/endpoint that we can use directly

```
U1 [shape=point width=0.2 color=red pos="2.5745,108"]
```

from the chosen edge above there are 2 valid 4-tuples to chose from resulting in 2 points on the splines (for divider2)

```
X1 [shape=point width=0.2 pos="11.59,171.75"]
X2 [shape=point width=0.2 pos="21.87,65.08"]
```

the combined file

```
digraph {
    graph [bb="0,0,74.575,252",
        nodesep=1,
        pad=0.5,
        rankdir=LR,
        ranksep=1
    ];
    node [label="\N",
        shape=circle
    ];
    edge [arrowhead=none];
    {
        graph [rank=same];
        A        [height=0.5,
            pos="56.575,234",
            width=0.5];
        B        [height=0.5,
            pos="56.575,126",
            width=0.5];
        A -> B       [pos="56.575,215.75 56.575,191.88 56.575,168.01 56.575,144.14"];
        C        [height=0.5,
            pos="56.575,18",
            width=0.5];
        A -> C       [pos="44.02,220.46 24.619,197.84 -9.2417,150.66 2.5745,108 10.795,78.323 31.695,48.606 44.952,31.836"];
        B -> C       [pos="56.575,107.75 56.575,83.878 56.575,60.01 56.575,36.141"];

        U1 [shape=point width=0.2 color=red pos="2.5745,108"]
        X1 [shape=point width=0.2 pos="11.59,171.75"]
        X2 [shape=point width=0.2 pos="21.87,65.08"]
    }
}
```

gives

[image]

Comment: This works in trivial example, but unfortunatelly it produces unacceptable output for real examples. As illustrated in edited question, there are two very bad properties. First, lines between nodes are now composed of 2 parts, e.g. y-z is not straight, and second, extra points change ranks of the nodes very much.

Comment: In that case you have to deal with manipulating the splines yourself. see my edit.

Comment: In my answer ther was a wrong definition of valid 4-tuples. I fixed that and added also the possibility of directly using spline handover points.

Comment: Again, this is a working solution but not usable in my approach. I cannot manipulate the graph after calling graphviz/dot. However, I will accept this answer if nobody propose more appropriate solution - I will assume that with graphviz/dot it is not possible to do better.